# A question on the cokernel of an $R$-map between free $R$-modules where $R$ is an euclidean domain

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an euclidean domain, and $A$ a $m\times n$ matrix. I want to prove two things:

1) The torsion submodules of $\mathrm{Coker}\;A$ and $\mathrm{Coker}\;A^T$ are isomorphic.

2)  $\mathrm{Coker}\;A$ and $\mathrm{Coker}\;A^T$ are isomorphic is and only if $n=m$.

Answer (score 2):

Up to multiplying on the left and right by invertible square matrices, you can assume that $A$ is diagonal—a keyword to find this is «Smith normal form». With that hypothesis, your two things are easy.